# mysql - find multiple rows referring to the same type of the joined rows

Tags: mysql, join, having

these are the table's data:

**Questions**:

```
id   type
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     3
5     1
```

**MyAnswers**:

```
rifQuestion  answer
1            aaa
2            bbb
3            ccc
4            ddd
5            eee
```

The link is: MyAnswers.rifQuestion = Questions.id

I need to select MyAnswers.rifQuestion (edit: and answer) only when in MyAnswers there is more than one record associated to the same Questions.type (all with one query Select).

**Edit:**

The record extracted must have a different "answer" each other but still referring to the same type.

**expected result**:

```
MyAnswers.rifQuestion   answer
1                       aaa
2                       bbb
5                       eee
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Alternatively, see JOIN.

Comment: You should edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: added the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM Questions
WHERE type IN  (SELECT Questions.type
                FROM MyAnswers INNER JOIN Questions ON MyAnswers.rifQuestion = Questions.id
                GROUP BY Questions.type
                HAVING COUNT(1) > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT Questions.id 
FROM Questions 
WHERE Questions.type IN 
 (SELECT Questions.type 
 FROM Questions
 GROUP BY type
 HAVING COUNT(question.id ) > 1;)
```

OR

```
SELECT MyAnswers.rifQuestion 
FROM MyAnswers 
LEFT JOIN Questions
ON Questions.id = MyAnswers.rifQuestion
WHERE Questions.type IN 
(SELECT Questions.type 
FROM Questions
GROUP BY type
HAVING COUNT(question.id ) > 1;)
```